# ul parent moving when ul ul active

Tags: jquery, html, css, html-lists, nested-lists

this might be a rather easy question to answer, however, I can't find a solution. I have built a very simple menu and whenever I hover over the ul parent it's child ul ul shall go visible. Basically it works, but the parent gives way to the it's children and I would like to keep it (the parent) in the position where it initially was. I have contructed a jfiddle, maybe someone can help me here?

Kind regards and thanks for your time

- Tim

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/merusame/Wzk8c/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

make the li relative and child ul absolute.

```
nav ul li{
    position:relative;
}

nav ul ul {
    display: none;
    z-index: 999;
    position:absolute;
    top:20px;
    left:0;
}
```

[jsFiddle File](http://jsfiddle.net/Wzk8c/2/)

hope this will work for you.
Thank you :)

Comment: But then the children are beneath each other and I'd love to have them next to each other

Comment: for this you have to adjust the css accordingly,  give a width to child ul and make the child li float:left